# No reversematch error eventhough pk is imported

Tags: python, html

I got a No reverseMatch Error evnthough pk has been imported.

Traceback:

```
Reverse for 'profile_page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile_page/(?P<pro>[^/]+)$']
```

urls.py:

```
path('profile_page/<str:pro>', UserProfileView, name='profile_page'),
```

Comment: Please post ```urls.py``` and ```views.py``` as well.

Comment: @Ram Yup Just did.

Comment: Where is your ```profile_post``` url route ? You have only posted ```profile_page``` route

Comment: @Ram I changed it into profile_page. I have edited it you can see the question now. Menaing no profile_post exists now.

Comment: And where are you using ```profile_page``` in your HTML ? Also, why are you creating models in your view ?

Comment: @Ram I deleted them in my models.py I am using that in my views.py, profile_page, urls, article details and home html. Also how do I fix this reverse match error.

Comment: Wherever you are using ```profile_page``` url you have to pass in a string because it expects a string along with it. Like this: ```{% url 'profile_page' <some string> %}```

Comment: @Ram I would love if you can give an example also as an answer. so hat I can close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reverse for 'profile_page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile_page/(?P<pro>[^/]+)$']
```

Your Error Traceback clearly says that no arguments are found for `profile_page` route.

Since your url route for `profile_page` accepts a string, you need to pass one

**urls.py**

```
path('profile_page/<str:pro>', UserProfileView, name='profile_page'),
```

Wherever you are navigating to `profile_page` in your HTML code. you have to pass a string along with it.

I suppose you are using this route to display the profile page of a user, then use this - `{% url 'profile_page' <some_user_name> %}`

> Eg: `<a href="{% url 'profile_page' 'Kaushik' %}">User</a>`